# Is there anyway to check some interval in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  id int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
  sku text NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  amount real NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT date_sku UNIQUE (sku,date)
)
```

Is there anyway to check for each sku if every 2 days average sales is bigger than for example 14 amount sold. I want to find date ranges, the percentage and amount it sold in those days.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1ci4bqtK)

for example for sku B in my example, it sold `15 at 2022-01-01` and `20 at 2022-01-02` and the average is 17.5 for these 2 days which is bigger than 14 therefore it will appear in my result and the change is 17.5 / 14 = 1.25.

Again for the next 2 days we have `20 at 2022-01-02` and `13 at 2022-01-03`. Therefore the average is 16.5 which is bigger than 14 and it will appear in the result
but for `13 at 2022-01-03` and `12 at 2022-01-04` and the average is about 12.5. Because 12.5 is not bigger than 14, it will not appear in the result.

my desired output with 14 amount example is:

```
sku     start_date    end_date    amount_sold    change_rate
B       2022-01-01    2022-01-02      17.5            1.25
B       2022-01-02    2022-01-03      16.5            1.17
D       2022-01-01    2022-01-02      28              2
```

I tried using `CASE WHEN` but I know that it wont work for large data like one year:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT sku,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-02' THEN amount END) AS first_in,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-01-02' AND '2022-01-03' THEN amount END) AS second_in,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-04' THEN amount END) AS third_in
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY sku
) AS t
WHERE first_in > 14
OR second_in > 14
OR third_in > 14
```

Comment: I have looked at your data and I have no idea what the values in `amount_sold` (or the grouping) and `change_percentage` are supposed to be. Why don't you edit yout question to explain that? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi - what does “14 amount” mean?

Comment: @Atmo i'm sorry for the confusing question. I have edited

Comment: @NickW 14 is just a number that was used in the calculations and its from user input.

Comment: You can create a temp table (or a cte), for each day you should store the average of that day and it's next day. Then query the temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, use the `LEAD` (or `LAG`) to retrieve data from the next or previous record. At least this is what I did before you asked for possibly several days. Other window functions are suitable for your need if you want more than 1 day:

```
SELECT *, averageamount/14
FROM (
SELECT sku, date,
MAX(date) OVER w AS nextdate,
AVG(amount) OVER w AS averageAmount
FROM sales
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN '0 day' PRECEDING AND '2 days' FOLLOWING )
) s
WHERE averageAmount > 14
```

This above select all the ranges that are up to 3 days long (days `D`, `D+1` and `D+2`). You may want to remove the ranges that are less than 3 days long by appending the additional condition:

```
AND nextdate >= date + interval '2 days'
```

Comment: This will only work for 1 day after. Is there anyway to expand this for example take every 3 days average?

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more general purpose.